# How to format the response of ajax POST request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How i get response from the server in the specific format i 'POST' the data to sever via ajax(XMLHttpRequest()) in the following format

```js
uid=1&body=LooseFlatBottomHem&sleeve=Cuff&neck=Rect&color=%23f7e7b2%2C%23f7e7b2%2C%23f7e7b2&Frontbody_elements=null&Backbody_elements=null&Frontsleeve_elements=null&Backsleeve_elements=null&Frontneck_elements=null&Backneck_elements=null&design_name=kjhkjhj&credit=48500&defaultTransform=662.36%2C359.47&front_svg=%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22svg%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20height%3D%221160%22%20width%3D%221920%22%20viewBox%3D%22709%20429%20502%20303%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22currentTab%22%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22currentTemplate%22%20transform%3D%22translate(662.36%2C359.47)%22%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22LooseFlatBottomHem%22%3E%3Cpath%20class%3D%22clipPath%20clipNeck%22%20fill%3D%22%23f7e7b2%22%20stroke%3D%22%23efcf65%22%20d%3D%22M329.66%2C99.99l22.1%2C4c0%2C0-6.9%2C45.5-2.1%2C51.6c0%2C0%2C15.1%2C115.36%2C14.1%2C186.36H231.57%20%20%20c-1-71%2C14.03-186.36%2C14.03-186.36c4.8-6.1-2.1-51.6-2.1-51.6l22.1-4%22%20clip-path%3D%22url(%23clippath_neck_front)%22%20vector-effect%3D%22non-scaling-stroke%22%20stroke-width%3D%221%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3CclipPath%20id%3D%22clippath_neck_front%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M329.558%2C99.994%20328.152%2C130.577%20297.628%2C131.478%20297.666%2C131.478%20267.142%2C130.577%20%20%20%20%20265.737%2C99.994%20%20%20M329.66%2C99.99l22.1%2C4c0%2C0-6.9%2C45.5-2.1%2C51.6c0%2C0%2C15.1%2C115.36%2C14.1%2C186.36H231.57%20%20%20c-1-71%2C14.03-186.36%2C14.03-186.36c4.8-6.1-2.1-51.6-2.1-51.6l22.1-4%22%20id%3D%22tmp_rule%22%20clip-rule%3D%22evenodd%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3C%2FclipPath%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3CclipPath%20id%3D%22body_clippath_front_1%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M329.66%2C99.99l22.1%2C4c0%2C0-6.9%2C45.5-2.1%2C51.6c0%2C0%2C15.1%2C115.36%2C14.1%2C186.36H231.57%20%20%20c-1-71%2C14.03-186.36%2C14.03-186.36c4.8-6.1-2.1-51.6-2.1-51.6l22.1-4%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3C%2FclipPath%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22Cuff%22%3E%3Cpath%20id%3D%22leftsleeve%22%20class%3D%22left%20extend%20clipPath%22%20stroke-width%3D%220.6%22%20fill%3D%22%23f7e7b2%22%20stroke%3D%22%23efcf65%22%20d%3D%22M245.611%2C155.598c-4%2C1.667-5.479%2C5.559-7.813%2C7.559s-28.292%2C40.538-31.909%2C46.569%20%20%20c-2.999%2C5-52.999%2C52-52.999%2C52l-11.668-13c0%2C0%2C35.254-49.74%2C36.667-52c3.333-5.334%2C21.081-26.883%2C25.667-34.334%20%20%20c6.158-10.008%2C21.176-54.66%2C40-58l0.006-0.016C243.563%2C104.376%2C250.385%2C149.451%2C245.611%2C155.598z%22%20vector-effect%3D%22non-scaling-stroke%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3Cpath%20class%3D%22left%20extend%20one%20restrict%22%20fill%3D%22%23f7e7b2%22%20stroke%3D%22%23efcf65%22%20d%3D%22M134.723%2C254.35L140.89%20240.058%20158.89%20259.059%20146.348%20267.725z%20M134.723%2C254.35L137.89%20241.058%20139.89%20241.725%22%20vector-effect%3D%22non-scaling-stroke%22%20stroke-width%3D%220.6%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3Cpath%20id%3D%22rightsleeve%22%20class%3D%22right%20clipPath%20extend%22%20fill%3D%22%23f7e7b2%22%20stroke%3D%22%23efcf65%22%20d%3D%22M349.661%2C155.599c4%2C1.667%2C5.479%2C5.559%2C7.813%2C7.559s28.292%2C40.538%2C31.909%2C46.569%20%20%20c2.999%2C5%2C52.999%2C52%2C52.999%2C52l11.668-13c0%2C0-35.254-49.74-36.667-52c-3.333-5.334-21.081-26.883-25.667-34.334%20%20%20c-6.158-10.008-21.176-54.66-40-58l-0.006-0.016C351.71%2C104.377%2C344.887%2C149.452%2C349.661%2C155.599z%22%20vector-effect%3D%22non-scaling-stroke%22%20stroke-width%3D%220.6%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3Cpath%20class%3D%22right%20extend%20one%20restrict%22%20fill%3D%22%23f7e7b2%22%20stroke%3D%22%23efcf65%22%20d%3D%22M460.549%2C254.351L454.382%20240.059%20436.382%20259.06%20448.924%20267.726z%20M460.549%2C254.351L457.382%20241.059%20455.382%20241.726%22%20vector-effect%3D%22non-scaling-stroke%22%20stroke-width%3D%220.6%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3CclipPath%20id%3D%22sleeve_left_clippath_front_1%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M245.611%2C155.598c-4%2C1.667-5.479%2C5.559-7.813%2C7.559s-28.292%2C40.538-31.909%2C46.569%20%20%20c-2.999%2C5-52.999%2C52-52.999%2C52l-11.668-13c0%2C0%2C35.254-49.74%2C36.667-52c3.333-5.334%2C21.081-26.883%2C25.667-34.334%20%20%20c6.158-10.008%2C21.176-54.66%2C40-58l0.006-0.016C243.563%2C104.376%2C250.385%2C149.451%2C245.611%2C155.598z%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3C%2FclipPath%3E%3CclipPath%20id%3D%22sleeve_right_clippath_front_2%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M349.661%2C155.599c4%2C1.667%2C5.479%2C5.559%2C7.813%2C7.559s28.292%2C40.538%2C31.909%2C46.569%20%20%20c2.999%2C5%2C52.999%2C52%2C52.999%2C52l11.668-13c0%2C0-35.254-49.74-36.667-52c-3.333-5.334-21.081-26.883-25.667-34.334%20%20%20c-6.158-10.008-21.176-54.66-40-58l-0.006-0.016C351.71%2C104.377%2C344.887%2C149.452%2C349.661%2C155.599z%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3C%2FclipPath%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22Rect%22%3E%3Cpath%20class%3D%22clipNeck%22%20fill%3D%22none%22%20d%3D%22M329.558%2C99.994%20328.152%2C130.577%20297.628%2C131.478%20297.666%2C131.478%20267.142%2C130.577%20%20%20%20%20265.737%2C99.994%20%20%20%22%20stroke%3D%22%23efcf65%22%20stroke-width%3D%220%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3Cpath%20id%3D%22vshape%22%20fill%3D%22none%22%20stroke%3D%22none%22%20d%3D%22M351.815%2C104.016%20329.558%2C99.994%20328.152%2C130.577%20297.628%2C131.478%20297.666%2C131.478%20%20%20%20%20267.142%2C130.577%20265.737%2C99.994%20243.479%2C104.016%20%20M%20243.51%20104%20L%20270.61%2099.1%20324.66%2099.1%20351.76%20104%20%22%20stroke-width%3D%220.3%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22currentElements%22%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22selectedGroup%22%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%20clip-path%3D%22url(%23body_clip_path_overview_front)%22%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22clippathparent%22%3E%3CclipPath%20id%3D%22body_clip_path_overview_front%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M329.66%2C99.99l22.1%2C4c0%2C0-6.9%2C45.5-2.1%2C51.6c0%2C0%2C15.1%2C115.36%2C14.1%2C186.36H231.57%20%20%20c-1-71%2C14.03-186.36%2C14.03-186.36c4.8-6.1-2.1-51.6-2.1-51.6l22.1-4%22%20transform%3D%22translate(662.36%2C359.47)%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M245.611%2C155.598c-4%2C1.667-5.479%2C5.559-7.813%2C7.559s-28.292%2C40.538-31.909%2C46.569%20%20%20c-2.999%2C5-52.999%2C52-52.999%2C52l-11.668-13c0%2C0%2C35.254-49.74%2C36.667-52c3.333-5.334%2C21.081-26.883%2C25.667-34.334%20%20%20c6.158-10.008%2C21.176-54.66%2C40-58l0.006-0.016C243.563%2C104.376%2C250.385%2C149.451%2C245.611%2C155.598z%22%20transform%3D%22translate(662.36%2C359.47)%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M134.723%2C254.35L140.89%20240.058%20158.89%20259.059%20146.348%20267.725z%20M134.723%2C254.35L137.89%20241.058%20139.89%20241.725%22%20transform%3D%22translate(662.36%2C359.47)%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M349.661%2C155.599c4%2C1.667%2C5.479%2C5.559%2C7.813%2C7.559s28.292%2C40.538%2C31.909%2C46.569%20%20%20c2.999%2C5%2C52.999%2C52%2C52.999%2C52l11.668-13c0%2C0-35.254-49.74-36.667-52c-3.333-5.334-21.081-26.883-25.667-34.334%20%20%20c-6.158-10.008-21.176-54.66-40-58l-0.006-0.016C351.71%2C104.377%2C344.887%2C149.452%2C349.661%2C155.599z%22%20transform%3D%22translate(662.36%2C359.47)%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M460.549%2C254.351L454.382%20240.059%20436.382%20259.06%20448.924%20267.726z%20M460.549%2C254.351L457.382%20241.059%20455.382%20241.726%22%20transform%3D%22translate(662.36%2C359.47)%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3C%2FclipPath%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%20clip-path%3D%22url(%23body_clip_path_overview_front)%22%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22Neck_Tmp_Tab%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M329.558%2C99.994%20328.152%2C130.577%20297.628%2C131.478%20297.666%2C131.478%20267.142%2C130.577%20%20%20%20%20265.737%2C99.994%20%20%20%22%20fill%3D%22%23f2f2f2%22%20transform%3D%22translate(662.36%2C359.47)%22%20id%3D%22tmp_path_neck%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E&back_svg=null&save_finish=save&description=null&other=null&viewbox=859%2C449%2C202%2C303&front_body_groups=null&back_body_groups=null&front_sleeve_groups=null&back_sleeve_groups=null&goldenratio=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&timersession=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&statistics=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&tags=null&new_same=new
```

The result of the above request is as follows:

```js
uid:1
body:LooseFlatBottomHem
sleeve:Cuff
neck:Rect
color:#f7e7b2,#f7e7b2,#f7e7b2
Frontbody_elements:null
Backbody_elements:null
Frontsleeve_elements:null
Backsleeve_elements:null
Frontneck_elements:null
Backneck_elements:null
design_name:kjhkjhj
credit:48500
defaultTransform:662.36,359.47
front_svg:<svg version="1.1" id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="1160" width="1920" viewBox="709 429 502 303"><defs></defs><g id="currentTab"><g id="currentTemplate" transform="translate(662.36,359.47)"><g id="LooseFlatBottomHem"><path class="clipPath clipNeck" fill="#f7e7b2" stroke="#efcf65" d="M329.66,99.99l22.1,4c0,0-6.9,45.5-2.1,51.6c0,0,15.1,115.36,14.1,186.36H231.57   c-1-71,14.03-186.36,14.03-186.36c4.8-6.1-2.1-51.6-2.1-51.6l22.1-4" clip-path="url(#clippath_neck_front)" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" stroke-width="1"></path><clipPath id="clippath_neck_front"><path d="M329.558,99.994 328.152,130.577 297.628,131.478 297.666,131.478 267.142,130.577     265.737,99.994   M329.66,99.99l22.1,4c0,0-6.9,45.5-2.1,51.6c0,0,15.1,115.36,14.1,186.36H231.57   c-1-71,14.03-186.36,14.03-186.36c4.8-6.1-2.1-51.6-2.1-51.6l22.1-4" id="tmp_rule" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></clipPath></g><g><clipPath id="body_clippath_front_1"><path d="M329.66,99.99l22.1,4c0,0-6.9,45.5-2.1,51.6c0,0,15.1,115.36,14.1,186.36H231.57   c-1-71,14.03-186.36,14.03-186.36c4.8-6.1-2.1-51.6-2.1-51.6l22.1-4"></path></clipPath></g><g id="Cuff"><path id="leftsleeve" class="left extend clipPath" stroke-width="0.6" fill="#f7e7b2" stroke="#efcf65" d="M245.611,155.598c-4,1.667-5.479,5.559-7.813,7.559s-28.292,40.538-31.909,46.569   c-2.999,5-52.999,52-52.999,52l-11.668-13c0,0,35.254-49.74,36.667-52c3.333-5.334,21.081-26.883,25.667-34.334   c6.158-10.008,21.176-54.66,40-58l0.006-0.016C243.563,104.376,250.385,149.451,245.611,155.598z" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></path><path class="left extend one restrict" fill="#f7e7b2" stroke="#efcf65" d="M134.723,254.35L140.89 240.058 158.89 259.059 146.348 267.725z M134.723,254.35L137.89 241.058 139.89 241.725" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" stroke-width="0.6"></path><path id="rightsleeve" class="right clipPath extend" fill="#f7e7b2" stroke="#efcf65" d="M349.661,155.599c4,1.667,5.479,5.559,7.813,7.559s28.292,40.538,31.909,46.569   c2.999,5,52.999,52,52.999,52l11.668-13c0,0-35.254-49.74-36.667-52c-3.333-5.334-21.081-26.883-25.667-34.334   c-6.158-10.008-21.176-54.66-40-58l-0.006-0.016C351.71,104.377,344.887,149.452,349.661,155.599z" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" stroke-width="0.6"></path><path class="right extend one restrict" fill="#f7e7b2" stroke="#efcf65" d="M460.549,254.351L454.382 240.059 436.382 259.06 448.924 267.726z M460.549,254.351L457.382 241.059 455.382 241.726" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" stroke-width="0.6"></path></g><g><clipPath id="sleeve_left_clippath_front_1"><path d="M245.611,155.598c-4,1.667-5.479,5.559-7.813,7.559s-28.292,40.538-31.909,46.569   c-2.999,5-52.999,52-52.999,52l-11.668-13c0,0,35.254-49.74,36.667-52c3.333-5.334,21.081-26.883,25.667-34.334   c6.158-10.008,21.176-54.66,40-58l0.006-0.016C243.563,104.376,250.385,149.451,245.611,155.598z"></path></clipPath><clipPath id="sleeve_right_clippath_front_2"><path d="M349.661,155.599c4,1.667,5.479,5.559,7.813,7.559s28.292,40.538,31.909,46.569   c2.999,5,52.999,52,52.999,52l11.668-13c0,0-35.254-49.74-36.667-52c-3.333-5.334-21.081-26.883-25.667-34.334   c-6.158-10.008-21.176-54.66-40-58l-0.006-0.016C351.71,104.377,344.887,149.452,349.661,155.599z"></path></clipPath></g><g id="Rect"><path class="clipNeck" fill="none" d="M329.558,99.994 328.152,130.577 297.628,131.478 297.666,131.478 267.142,130.577     265.737,99.994   " stroke="#efcf65" stroke-width="0"></path><path id="vshape" fill="none" stroke="none" d="M351.815,104.016 329.558,99.994 328.152,130.577 297.628,131.478 297.666,131.478     267.142,130.577 265.737,99.994 243.479,104.016  M 243.51 104 L 270.61 99.1 324.66 99.1 351.76 104 " stroke-width="0.3"></path></g></g><g id="currentElements"><g id="selectedGroup"></g><g clip-path="url(#body_clip_path_overview_front)"></g><g id="clippathparent"><clipPath id="body_clip_path_overview_front"><path d="M329.66,99.99l22.1,4c0,0-6.9,45.5-2.1,51.6c0,0,15.1,115.36,14.1,186.36H231.57   c-1-71,14.03-186.36,14.03-186.36c4.8-6.1-2.1-51.6-2.1-51.6l22.1-4" transform="translate(662.36,359.47)"></path><path d="M245.611,155.598c-4,1.667-5.479,5.559-7.813,7.559s-28.292,40.538-31.909,46.569   c-2.999,5-52.999,52-52.999,52l-11.668-13c0,0,35.254-49.74,36.667-52c3.333-5.334,21.081-26.883,25.667-34.334   c6.158-10.008,21.176-54.66,40-58l0.006-0.016C243.563,104.376,250.385,149.451,245.611,155.598z" transform="translate(662.36,359.47)"></path><path d="M134.723,254.35L140.89 240.058 158.89 259.059 146.348 267.725z M134.723,254.35L137.89 241.058 139.89 241.725" transform="translate(662.36,359.47)"></path><path d="M349.661,155.599c4,1.667,5.479,5.559,7.813,7.559s28.292,40.538,31.909,46.569   c2.999,5,52.999,52,52.999,52l11.668-13c0,0-35.254-49.74-36.667-52c-3.333-5.334-21.081-26.883-25.667-34.334   c-6.158-10.008-21.176-54.66-40-58l-0.006-0.016C351.71,104.377,344.887,149.452,349.661,155.599z" transform="translate(662.36,359.47)"></path><path d="M460.549,254.351L454.382 240.059 436.382 259.06 448.924 267.726z M460.549,254.351L457.382 241.059 455.382 241.726" transform="translate(662.36,359.47)"></path></clipPath></g><g clip-path="url(#body_clip_path_overview_front)"></g></g></g><g id="Neck_Tmp_Tab"><path d="M329.558,99.994 328.152,130.577 297.628,131.478 297.666,131.478 267.142,130.577     265.737,99.994   " fill="#f2f2f2" transform="translate(662.36,359.47)" id="tmp_path_neck"></path></g></svg>
back_svg:null
save_finish:save
description:null
other:null
viewbox:859,449,202,303
front_body_groups:null
back_body_groups:null
front_sleeve_groups:null
back_sleeve_groups:null
goldenratio:[object Object]
timersession:[object Object]
statistics:[object Object]
tags:null
new_same:new
```

but in order to process data i want the response in the following format

```js
uid:1
body:LooseFlatBottomHem
sleeve:Cuff
neck:Rect
color:%23f7e7b2%2C%23f7e7b2%2C%23f7e7b2
Frontbody_elements:
Backbody_elements:
Frontsleeve_elements:
Backsleeve_elements:
Frontneck_elements:
Backneck_elements:
design_name:khnkh
credit:48500
defaultTransform:662.36%2C359.47
front_svg:%3Csvg+version%3D%221.1%22+id%3D%22svg%22+xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22+xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22+height%3D%221160%22+width%3D%221920%22+viewBox%3D%22709+429+502+303%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg+id%3D%22currentTab%22%3E%3Cg+id%3D%22currentTemplate%22+transform%3D%22translate(662.36%2C359.47)%22%3E%3Cg+id%3D%22LooseFlatBottomHem%22%3E%3Cpath+class%3D%22clipPath+clipNeck%22+fill%3D%22%23f7e7b2%22+stroke%3D%22%23efcf65%22+d%3D%22M329.66%2C99.99l22.1%2C4c0%2C0-6.9%2C45.5-2.1%2C51.6c0%2C0%2C15.1%2C115.36%2C14.1%2C186.36H231.57+++c-1-71%2C14.03-186.36%2C14.03-186.36c4.8-6.1-2.1-51.6-2.1-51.6l22.1-4%22+clip-path%3D%22url(%23clippath_neck_front)%22+vector-effect%3D%22non-scaling-stroke%22+stroke-width%3D%221%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3CclipPath+id%3D%22clippath_neck_front%22%3E%3Cpath+d%3D%22M329.558%2C99.994+328.152%2C130.577+297.628%2C131.478+297.666%2C131.478+267.142%2C130.577+++++265.737%2C99.994+++M329.66%2C99.99l22.1%2C4c0%2C0-6.9%2C45.5-2.1%2C51.6c0%2C0%2C15.1%2C115.36%2C14.1%2C186.36H231.57+++c-1-71%2C14.03-186.36%2C14.03-186.36c4.8-6.1-2.1-51.6-2.1-51.6l22.1-4%22+id%3D%22tmp_rule%22+clip-rule%3D%22evenodd%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3C%2FclipPath%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3CclipPath+id%3D%22body_clippath_front_1%22%3E%3Cpath+d%3D%22M329.66%2C99.99l22.1%2C4c0%2C0-6.9%2C45.5-2.1%2C51.6c0%2C0%2C15.1%2C115.36%2C14.1%2C186.36H231.57+++c-1-71%2C14.03-186.36%2C14.03-186.36c4.8-6.1-2.1-51.6-2.1-51.6l22.1-4%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3C%2FclipPath%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg+id%3D%22Cuff%22%3E%3Cpath+id%3D%22leftsleeve%22+class%3D%22left+extend+clipPath%22+stroke-width%3D%220.6%22+fill%3D%22%23f7e7b2%22+stroke%3D%22%23efcf65%22+d%3D%22M245.611%2C155.598c-4%2C1.667-5.479%2C5.559-7.813%2C7.559s-28.292%2C40.538-31.909%2C46.569+++c-2.999%2C5-52.999%2C52-52.999%2C52l-11.668-13c0%2C0%2C35.254-49.74%2C36.667-52c3.333-5.334%2C21.081-26.883%2C25.667-34.334+++c6.158-10.008%2C21.176-54.66%2C40-58l0.006-0.016C243.563%2C104.376%2C250.385%2C149.451%2C245.611%2C155.598z%22+vector-effect%3D%22non-scaling-stroke%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3Cpath+class%3D%22left+extend+one+restrict%22+fill%3D%22%23f7e7b2%22+stroke%3D%22%23efcf65%22+d%3D%22M134.723%2C254.35L140.89+240.058+158.89+259.059+146.348+267.725z+M134.723%2C254.35L137.89+241.058+139.89+241.725%22+vector-effect%3D%22non-scaling-stroke%22+stroke-width%3D%220.6%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3Cpath+id%3D%22rightsleeve%22+class%3D%22right+clipPath+extend%22+fill%3D%22%23f7e7b2%22+stroke%3D%22%23efcf65%22+d%3D%22M349.661%2C155.599c4%2C1.667%2C5.479%2C5.559%2C7.813%2C7.559s28.292%2C40.538%2C31.909%2C46.569+++c2.999%2C5%2C52.999%2C52%2C52.999%2C52l11.668-13c0%2C0-35.254-49.74-36.667-52c-3.333-5.334-21.081-26.883-25.667-34.334+++c-6.158-10.008-21.176-54.66-40-58l-0.006-0.016C351.71%2C104.377%2C344.887%2C149.452%2C349.661%2C155.599z%22+vector-effect%3D%22non-scaling-stroke%22+stroke-width%3D%220.6%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3Cpath+class%3D%22right+extend+one+restrict%22+fill%3D%22%23f7e7b2%22+stroke%3D%22%23efcf65%22+d%3D%22M460.549%2C254.351L454.382+240.059+436.382+259.06+448.924+267.726z+M460.549%2C254.351L457.382+241.059+455.382+241.726%22+vector-effect%3D%22non-scaling-stroke%22+stroke-width%3D%220.6%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3CclipPath+id%3D%22sleeve_left_clippath_front_1%22%3E%3Cpath+d%3D%22M245.611%2C155.598c-4%2C1.667-5.479%2C5.559-7.813%2C7.559s-28.292%2C40.538-31.909%2C46.569+++c-2.999%2C5-52.999%2C52-52.999%2C52l-11.668-13c0%2C0%2C35.254-49.74%2C36.667-52c3.333-5.334%2C21.081-26.883%2C25.667-34.334+++c6.158-10.008%2C21.176-54.66%2C40-58l0.006-0.016C243.563%2C104.376%2C250.385%2C149.451%2C245.611%2C155.598z%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3C%2FclipPath%3E%3CclipPath+id%3D%22sleeve_right_clippath_front_2%22%3E%3Cpath+d%3D%22M349.661%2C155.599c4%2C1.667%2C5.479%2C5.559%2C7.813%2C7.559s28.292%2C40.538%2C31.909%2C46.569+++c2.999%2C5%2C52.999%2C52%2C52.999%2C52l11.668-13c0%2C0-35.254-49.74-36.667-52c-3.333-5.334-21.081-26.883-25.667-34.334+++c-6.158-10.008-21.176-54.66-40-58l-0.006-0.016C351.71%2C104.377%2C344.887%2C149.452%2C349.661%2C155.599z%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3C%2FclipPath%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg+id%3D%22Rect%22%3E%3Cpath+class%3D%22clipNeck%22+fill%3D%22none%22+d%3D%22M329.558%2C99.994+328.152%2C130.577+297.628%2C131.478+297.666%2C131.478+267.142%2C130.577+++++265.737%2C99.994+++%22+stroke%3D%22%23efcf65%22+stroke-width%3D%220%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3Cpath+id%3D%22vshape%22+fill%3D%22none%22+stroke%3D%22none%22+d%3D%22M351.815%2C104.016+329.558%2C99.994+328.152%2C130.577+297.628%2C131.478+297.666%2C131.478+++++267.142%2C130.577+265.737%2C99.994+243.479%2C104.016++M+243.51+104+L+270.61+99.1+324.66+99.1+351.76+104+%22+stroke-width%3D%220.3%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg+id%3D%22currentElements%22%3E%3Cg+id%3D%22selectedGroup%22%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg+clip-path%3D%22url(%23body_clip_path_overview_front)%22%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg+id%3D%22clippathparent%22%3E%3CclipPath+id%3D%22body_clip_path_overview_front%22%3E%3Cpath+d%3D%22M329.66%2C99.99l22.1%2C4c0%2C0-6.9%2C45.5-2.1%2C51.6c0%2C0%2C15.1%2C115.36%2C14.1%2C186.36H231.57+++c-1-71%2C14.03-186.36%2C14.03-186.36c4.8-6.1-2.1-51.6-2.1-51.6l22.1-4%22+transform%3D%22translate(662.36%2C359.47)%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3Cpath+d%3D%22M245.611%2C155.598c-4%2C1.667-5.479%2C5.559-7.813%2C7.559s-28.292%2C40.538-31.909%2C46.569+++c-2.999%2C5-52.999%2C52-52.999%2C52l-11.668-13c0%2C0%2C35.254-49.74%2C36.667-52c3.333-5.334%2C21.081-26.883%2C25.667-34.334+++c6.158-10.008%2C21.176-54.66%2C40-58l0.006-0.016C243.563%2C104.376%2C250.385%2C149.451%2C245.611%2C155.598z%22+transform%3D%22translate(662.36%2C359.47)%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3Cpath+d%3D%22M134.723%2C254.35L140.89+240.058+158.89+259.059+146.348+267.725z+M134.723%2C254.35L137.89+241.058+139.89+241.725%22+transform%3D%22translate(662.36%2C359.47)%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3Cpath+d%3D%22M349.661%2C155.599c4%2C1.667%2C5.479%2C5.559%2C7.813%2C7.559s28.292%2C40.538%2C31.909%2C46.569+++c2.999%2C5%2C52.999%2C52%2C52.999%2C52l11.668-13c0%2C0-35.254-49.74-36.667-52c-3.333-5.334-21.081-26.883-25.667-34.334+++c-6.158-10.008-21.176-54.66-40-58l-0.006-0.016C351.71%2C104.377%2C344.887%2C149.452%2C349.661%2C155.599z%22+transform%3D%22translate(662.36%2C359.47)%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3Cpath+d%3D%22M460.549%2C254.351L454.382+240.059+436.382+259.06+448.924+267.726z+M460.549%2C254.351L457.382+241.059+455.382+241.726%22+transform%3D%22translate(662.36%2C359.47)%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3C%2FclipPath%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg+clip-path%3D%22url(%23body_clip_path_overview_front)%22%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg+id%3D%22Neck_Tmp_Tab%22%3E%3Cpath+d%3D%22M329.558%2C99.994+328.152%2C130.577+297.628%2C131.478+297.666%2C131.478+267.142%2C130.577+++++265.737%2C99.994+++%22+fill%3D%22%23f2f2f2%22+transform%3D%22translate(662.36%2C359.47)%22+id%3D%22tmp_path_neck%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E
back_svg:
save_finish:save
description:
other:
viewbox:859%2C449%2C202%2C303
front_body_groups:
back_body_groups:
front_sleeve_groups:
back_sleeve_groups:
goldenratio%5Bwr%5D:3.825
goldenratio%5Bhr%5D:3.828
goldenratio%5Bw%5D:1920
goldenratio%5Bh%5D:1160
timersession%5Bstarttime%5D:1445670416576
timersession%5Bendtime%5D:1445670421669
timersession%5Btimeused%5D:5
statistics%5Bopeningpopup-new%5D:1
statistics%5Bselecttemplatetype-bodies%2CLooseFlatBottomHem%2C0%5D:1
statistics%5Btemplateselectiontab-sleeves%5D:1
statistics%5Bselecttemplatetype-sleeves%2CCuff%2C1%5D:1
statistics%5Btemplateselectiontab-necks%5D:1
statistics%5Bselecttemplatetype-necks%2CRect%2C2%5D:1
statistics%5Bfinishnewtemplate%5D:1
statistics%5Bnewtemplatename-save%5D:1
tags:
new_same:new
```

How convert my data to following format?

Comment: so you want it to be url-encoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First , of all your question is not clear .
But @gapvision said , if you want it to be url-encoded , then add this line :

```
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // ->Use your own object and encode the URL
hr.setRequestHeader("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

You can also refer to this link . [URL Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data)